# jQuery based div class check and CSS edit

Tags: jquery, css

I have this Navigation-menu, where i want current-page selector's tab background to be changed via jQuery.

```
 <nav class="nav-container">
<ul id="main_menu" class="main_menu">


<li class="menu-item">
<a style="border-radius: 0px" class="button" href="who-are-we.php">Tab 1</a>
</li>

<li class="menu-item current-menu-ancestor active">
<a style="border-radius: 0px" class="button" href="who-are-we.php">Tab 2</a>
</li>

<li class="menu-item">
<a style="border-radius: 0px" class="button" href="who-are-we.php">Tab 3</a>
</li>

<li class="menu-item">
<a style="border-radius: 0px" class="button" href="who-are-we.php">Tab 4</a>
</li>

</ul>

</nav>
```

I want to add, style="background-color:aqua;", to  of Tab 2.

I want to follow this logic :

```
jquery if ( li contains class="current-menu-ancestor active" ) {

a style add "background-color: aqua;"

}
```

How to do this , please ??

Comment: It's not clear why you need scripting for this. Why can't you just use CSS?

Comment: Bcoz, I want to INJECT active class  in BOM dynamically. But its not working. https://jsfiddle.net/gocwqmtr/ See JSFiddle plz, Thanks

Comment: 1) Stop typing in phone text message shorthand, and take the time to format your markup and code. Act like a professional if you expect professionalism from your volunteers. 2) Listen to what the pros are telling you here. From what we can tell, *you don't need JavaScript to apply your style*. See the demo on Louys' answer. If that doesn't address your question, you need to revise your post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just using CSS, it would be:

```
.menu-item.active a{
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

And to change the `.active` class on click, if not already handled another way(?):

```
$(".menu-item a").on("click",function(){
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent(".menu-item").addClass("active");
}
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zqnfbv0a/)

Comment: @tazcoder, I added a demo. Take note of the dramatically simplified script and CSS.